# Drawing a sample that changes the shape of the mother sample

Tags: r, random, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

**Background:**

I'm trying to modify the shape of a histogram resulted from an "**Initial**" large sample obtained using `Initial = rbeta(1e5, 2, 3)`. Specifically, I want the modified version of the Initial large sample to have **2 additional smaller** (in height) **"humps"** (i.e., another 2 smaller-height peaks in addition to the one that existed in the Initial large sample).

**Coding Question:**

I'm wondering how to manipulate `sample()` (maybe using its `prob` argument) in R base so that this command samples in a manner that the two additional **humps** be around **".5"** and **".6"** on the X-Axis?

**Here is my current R code:**

```
Initial = rbeta(1e5, 2, 3) ## My initial Large Sample

hist (Initial)             ## As seen, here there is only one "hump" say near 
                            # less than ".4" on the X-Axis


Modified.Initial = sample(Initial, 1e4 ) ## This is meant to be the modified version of the
                                          # the Initial with two additional "humps"

hist(Modified.Initial)          ## Here, I need to see two additional "humps" near  
                                 # ".5" and ".6" on the X-Axis
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the density distribution by combining it with beta distributions with the desired modes for a smoothed adjustment.

```r
set.seed(47)

Initial = rbeta(1e5, 2, 3)
d <- density(Initial)

# Generate densities of beta distribution. Parameters determine center (0.5) and spread.
b.5 <- dbeta(seq(0, 1, length.out = length(d$y)), 50, 50)
b.5 <- b.5 / (max(b.5) / max(d$y))    # Scale down to max of original density

# Repeat centered at 0.6
b.6 <- dbeta(seq(0, 1, length.out = length(d$y)), 60, 40)
b.6 <- b.6 / (max(b.6) / max(d$y))

# Collect maximum densities at each x to use as sample probability weights
p <- pmax(d$y, b.5, b.6)

plot(p, type = 'l')
```

[image]

```r
# Sample from density breakpoints with new probability weights
Final <- sample(d$x, 1e4, replace = TRUE, prob = p)
```

Effects on histogram are subtle...

```r
hist(Final)
```

[image]

...but are more obvious in the density plot.

```r
plot(density(Final))
```

[image]

Obviously all adjustments are arbitrary. Please don't do terrible things with your power.